# RadioGroup null RadioButton in alertdialog en restore preferences

Tags: java, android, android-studio

me gustaría por favor si me podeis ayudar a saber lo que pasa. Tengo un radiogroup construido en un alertDialog. El problema es que me da distintos id al reconstruir la actividad cuando llamo al fichero de preferencias para restaurar la opcion que el usuario marco.

```
        findViewById(R.id._signupEridelevel).setOnClickListener((View v) ->{
            AlertDialog.Builder ridelevelbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(_SingUp.this);
            View vistalayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.build_dl_ridelevel, null);
            RadioGroup rg = vistalayout.findViewById(R.id.build_ridelevel);
            ridelevelbuilder.setView(vistalayout);
            AlertDialog dial = ridelevelbuilder.create();
            // RECUPERAR EN FICHERO DE PREFERENCIAS
        // SI NO HAY PREFERENCIAS ME MARCA EL RADIOBUTTON PRINCIPAL QUE ES EL PRIMERO
            SharedPreferences pref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            int choose = pref.getInt(PREFERENCIA_MONTA, R.id.build_ridelevel_default);
                    // eliminado porque daba NULL (EL PROBLEMA) RadioButton vt = (RadioButton)vistalayout.findViewById(choose);
                    // ELIMINADO(vt).setChecked(true);
            for(int x=0; x<rg.getChildCount();x++){
                int m = rg.getChildAt(x).getId();
                Log.i("RADIOGROUP",m+"");
            }
            dial.show();
            vistalayout.findViewById(R.id.build_ridelevel_accept).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // GUARDAR EN FICHERO DE PREFERENCIAS
        //AQUI LO GUARDO
                    SharedPreferences pref2 = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = pref2.edit();
                    int id  =((RadioGroup)vistalayout.findViewById(R.id.build_ridelevel)).getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    Log.i("RADIO GUARDADO",id+"");
                    ed.putInt(PREFERENCIA_MONTA,((RadioGroup)vistalayout.findViewById(R.id.build_ridelevel)).getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                    ed.commit();
                    dial.dismiss();
                }
            });*
                            Log.i("RADIO GUARDADO",id+"");
                            ed.putInt(PREFERENCIA_MONTA,((RadioGroup)vistalayout.findViewById(R.id.build_ridelevel)).getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                            ed.commit();
                            dial.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
```

Me daba null pointer exception por lo que viendo me daba diferentes id. 
CONSOLA:**pantalla vertical**

I/RADIOGROUP: 2131296319
              3
I/RADIOGROUP: 4
              5
I/RADIOGROUP: 6
I/RADIO GUARDADO: 3
CONSOLA:**pantalla horizontal**
I/RADIOGROUP: 9
I/RADIOGROUP: 10
I/RADIOGROUP: 11
              12

¿Alguien tiene alguna solución?
Gracias

Comment: Hola Sara, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Comment: No es necesario duplicar preguntas,  lo mejor es realizar una pregunta de acuerdo a [ask]. Agrega el mensaje de error especificado en el LogCat.